# Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row MYSQL

Tags: mysql

A coluna que estou adicionando na *subquery* tem mais de um registro, mas não sei como resolver:

```sql
 select productid,pb.pricebookid,(select bookname from vtiger_pricebook p 
   inner join vtiger_pricebookproductrel pbp
    on p.pricebookid = pbp.pricebookid
    where pbp.pricebookid = '299182') Wx
    from vtiger_pricebookproductrel pbp
    join vtiger_pricebook pb
    ON pb.pricebookid = pbp.pricebookid
```

Colocando um `limit` de 1, ele retorna um resultado que se repete porque usei `limit 1` só para ver se ia retornar. Tirando isso fala que há um erro porque tenho mais de um registro na minha subquery:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que retorne:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não consigo retornar tudo porque minha *subquery* retorna mais de um registro.

Como faço para que a minha subquery retorne mais de um registro?

Comment: Sem conhecer a estrutura do seu banco é difícil.

Comment: ja vou editar para deixar mais claro

Comment: Pra que usar subquery num caso desses em vez de um JOIN? É importante [edit] e reduzir o problema a um [mcve], e dar um exemplo de como é o dataset, o que pretende e como deveria ser o resultado

Answer (score 1):

Então galera, para conseguir tive que usar `wheren in` no caso, a minha consulta fico asssim:

```
select productid,pb.pricebookid, listprice
from vtiger_pricebookproductrel pbp
join vtiger_pricebook pb
ON pb.pricebookid = pbp.pricebookid
where pb.bookname in (select listprice from vtiger_pricebook p inner join vtiger_pricebookproductrel pbp
on p.pricebookid = pbp.pricebookid
where pbp.pricebookid = '299182')
```

> WHERE pb.bookname IN depois coloquei a minha subquery e deu certo!